Proof review Tempered Distributions: $(T*\varphi)^\wedge = (2\pi)^{n/2} \hat{\varphi}\hat{T}$ and computing $(x^\alpha)^\wedge$
I am learning about tempered distributions on schwartz space. But there are 2 questions in this text where Im unsatisfied with my solution... I ask kindly for your review of my solutions below, and if you have any advice to understand the concepts better, or find any flaws in my solutions. Thanks!

QUESTION 1. Given tempered distribution $T$ and schwartz function $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the fourier transform of their convolution, where convolution is defined as the following function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $$(T*\varphi)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} T(y) \varphi(x-y)dx,$$ satisfies: $$ (T*\varphi)^\wedge = (2\pi)^{n/2} \hat{\varphi}\hat{T}. $$
I struggle with the abuse of notation, that sometimes it's 'ok' to use a distribution in the same way as a function. Since, for example, if $T$ was the dirac delta distribution, the following solution would not make sense... My solution to Q1 is as follows. I expand all the definitions, change the order of integrations ($dydx\mapsto dxdy$, haven't verified yet if it is valid), and change of variable ($y\mapsto x-y$).
$$(T*\varphi)^\wedge(\xi)$$
$$=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-ix\cdot \xi}(T*\varphi)(x) dx$$
$$=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-ix\cdot \xi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} T(y) \varphi(x-y)dydx$$
$$=(2\pi)^{-n/2}(2\pi)^{-n/2}(2\pi)^{n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i(x-y+y)\cdot \xi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} T(y) \varphi(x-y)dydx$$
$$=(2\pi)^{-n/2}(2\pi)^{-n/2}(2\pi)^{n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i(x-y+y)\cdot \xi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} T(y) \varphi(x-y)dxdy$$
$$=(2\pi)^{-n/2}(2\pi)^{-n/2}(2\pi)^{n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i(y)\cdot \xi}T(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i(x-y)\cdot \xi} \varphi(x-y)dxdy$$
$$= (2\pi)^{n/2} \hat{\varphi}(\xi)\hat{T}(\xi)$$

QUESTION 2. Given $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any multi-index $\alpha$, compute $\hat{f}$.
Some notation: Multi-index $\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m)$ each coordinate non-negative. Partial derivative operator $D^\alpha = (-i)^{|\alpha|} \partial^\alpha = (-i)^{|\alpha|} \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}_1 ... \partial x^{\alpha_m}_m}$. Dirac Delta is a tempered distribution (continuous linear functional on schwartz space) such that $\delta(\varphi)=\varphi(0)$.
My solution:

Fact 1: $(D^\alpha \delta)^\wedge(\varphi)=x^\alpha \hat{\delta}(\varphi)$, for all $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}$.

Fact 2: Fourier transform turns product of tempered distributions into product of their transforms $\times (2\pi)^{-n/2}.

Fact 3: Inverse fourier property of tempered distributions and schwartz functions $((T)^\wedge)^\wedge = \tilde{T}$ and $((\varphi)^\wedge)^\wedge = \tilde{\varphi}$


Using these facts, the best I can do is express $\hat{f}=(x^\alpha)^\wedge$ as the solution to a differential equation of Delta:
$$(D^\alpha \delta)^\wedge(\varphi)=x^\alpha \hat{\delta}(\varphi)$$
$$\implies ((D^\alpha \delta)^\wedge)^\wedge(\varphi)=(x^\alpha \hat{\delta})^\wedge(\varphi)$$
$$\implies (D^\alpha \delta)(\tilde{\varphi})=(2\pi)^{-n/2}(x^\alpha)^\wedge \delta(\hat{\varphi})$$
$$\implies (-1)^{|\alpha|}(2\pi)^{n/2}(\partial^\alpha \delta)(\tilde{\varphi})=\hat{f} \delta(\hat{\varphi})$$

The Fourier transform of powers of $x$ should give you derivatives of the Dirac delta. Something went a little sideways in your second computation.

@CameronWilliams Yeah, i think my approch on Q2 is all wrong, because not all schwartz functions have $\hat{\varphi}(0)=1$... i wish I could divide both sides instead, but also cant guarantee $\hat{\varphi}(0)\neq 0$. Or can i?

@CameronWilliams I updated my solution but its not a direct formula...

For your first question, I think your question is very good, usually we do such operate and regard distribution as function when do some calculations, I think the reason is that schwarz function space is dense in distribution space. I don't know too much distribution theory, but I think if you don't familiar with the dense theorem, you should check the definition. Below is my own opinion:
\begin{align}
\langle\widehat{T*\varphi},\psi\rangle&=\langle{T*\varphi},\widehat{\psi}\rangle\\&=\langle T,\tilde{\varphi}*\widehat{\psi}\rangle\\&=\langle T,\widehat{\check{\tilde{\varphi}}\psi}\rangle\\&=\langle\widehat{T},\check{\tilde{\varphi}}\psi\rangle\\&=\langle\widehat{T},\hat{\varphi}\psi\rangle\\&=\langle\hat{\varphi}\widehat{T},\psi\rangle
\end{align}
where the fourier transform I use is $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}f(x)dx$$
For your second question, I think it is easy, by duality bracket, we have
\begin{align}
\langle\widehat{x^{\alpha}},\varphi\rangle&=\langle x^{\alpha},\widehat{\varphi}\rangle\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}x^{\alpha}\widehat{\varphi}\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{1}{(-2\pi i)^{|\alpha|}}\widehat{\partial^{\alpha}\varphi}d\xi\\&=\frac{1}{(-2\pi i)^{|\alpha|}}\langle 1,\widehat{\partial^{\alpha}\varphi}\rangle\\&=\frac{1}{(-2\pi i)^{|\alpha|}}\langle\hat{1},\partial^{\alpha}\varphi\rangle\\&=\frac{1}{(-2\pi i)^{|\alpha|}}(-1)^{\alpha}\langle\partial^{\alpha}\hat{1},\varphi\rangle\\&=\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^{|\alpha|}}\langle\partial^{\alpha}\delta,\varphi\rangle
\end{align}

Thank you for the additional information, I will accept your answer. Although I am definitely still searching for satisfactory explanations why we can abuse notations and still call it rigorous.. The fact that schwartz space is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ does not seem to reconcile my issues

I think the book GTM252: Distributions and operators is suitable for you.
